# Delayed Wake Up Time

Tags: cyanogenmod, lg-g3

I'm having issues with my LG G3 CM13. Whenever it's locked and I double tap the screen or press the button on the back, it takes about 5 seconds for it to wake up. Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: are you using a custom launcher? do you have any other applications running that may hog resources?

Comment: I'm using the default trebuchet that comes with cm13. When my phone has been locked for a while, it unlocks instantly. But when I lock it and then go to unlock it, it takes forever

Comment: Are you using stock CM13 kernel or something else? Since there is no stable  CM13 yet, your issue may be resolved in another nightly build if you report it to CM. Try it.